# Error with heredoc in PHP

Tags: php, heredoc

This code:

```
<?
echo <<<EOM 
Hello
EOM;
?>
```

Results in this error:

> Parse error: parse error in C:\xampp\htdocs\tiketku\cari.php on line 2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right file?

Comment: yes im sure.. i get this code from the book and its should get output.. "Hello".. but im get an error.. do you know how to solve this?

Comment: A word of advice while you're still in the early learning process: get used to always using the complete opening tag <?php, rather than just <?. The short tag is not compatible with all PHP installations, since it depends on a php.ini setting and is therefor a bad practice.

Answer (score 11):

You have a space after `<<<EOM`. This is illegal. Remove the space and it will work fine.

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: `<<<`. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline.

You can't have whitespace between the identifier and the new line.

Comment: Ah jeez. +1. I *edited* the question and missed that.

Comment: really? i rather to believe this is a typo

Answer (score 4):

You have a space ␣ after the `EOM`.

```
<?
echo <<<EOM␣
Hello
EOM;
?>
```

You need to remove it.

Comment: i just remove the space like this `<?php
echo <<<EOMHello
EOM;?>`

but still get errors...
pls help

Comment: You need to keep the line breaks, of course. There was just one space to remove. -- Also elucidate your new error message.

Comment: OK.. i solve the problem.. thanx mario and all of you master..

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra space character after the first "EOM"!

Comment: i just remove the space like this '<?php
echo <<<EOMHello
EOM;?>'